# Shift events in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way I can shift **all** events in my Google Calendar, +/- a week?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this through the Google Calendar web app since it's built for interacting with one event at a time. See:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=27e916d34ae71145&hl=en

You might be able to accomplish this using a third-party client such as Thunderbird or Outlook.

Of course, if you wanted to you could write a script to do this for you. Remember to use some kind of date module to do the "add a week" feature, since adding a week to a calendar date can get very tricky. See the Calendar Data API:

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html